# How do I attach an Elastic IP to an Elastic Beanstalk app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip, amazon-beanstalk

I can give a single instance an Elastic IP. No problem.

But I have an Elastic Beanstalk app. It can create and remove instances as needed. It has a load balancer. How can I get these features (Elastic IP and Elastic Beanstalk) to work together?

Ultimately, all I want to do is make calls to my server through my domain like this:
mydomain.com/someApiCall
and I don't want to worry about my Elastic IP becoming "detached."

Answer (score 8):

That is currently not possible and actually a limitation of the [Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) in use, see e.g. [Why does Amazon not allow assigning an Elastic IP to an Elastic Load Balancer?](http://www.quora.com/Why-does-Amazon-not-allow-assigning-an-Elastic-IP-to-an-Elastic-Load-Balancer):

> The elastic load balancer is simply a collection of individual
>   software load balancers hosted within EC2, with DNS load balancing
>   traffic among them. The pool can contain many IPs, at least one per
>   availability zone, and depending on traffic levels.

D.Svanlunds's answer to [Load balancers and elastic IP](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=304857#304857) provides a good summary of why ELB is designed this way, and Shlomo Swidler's [The “Elastic” in “Elastic Load Balancing”: ELB Elasticity and How to Test it](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/elastic-in-elastic-load-balancing-elb.html) provides an early but in-depth analysis of the ELB architecture and the implications for testing a web application in this context.

---

#### Update

Regarding your comment: You are communicating with your [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) application via the DNS name mapped to the *Elastic Load Balancer*, to which you can map a [CNAME record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) in turn as usual, see [Overview of Elastic Load Balancing](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/arch-loadbalancing.html):

> Elastic Load Balancing automatically generates a DNS name for each
>   load balancer. You can map any other domain name (such as
>   www.example.com) to the automatically generated DNS name using CNAME
>   or use an [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) alias for the load balancer's DNS name.

Further details can be found in [Using Domain Names With Elastic Load Balancing](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html), which *describes how to associate your Elastic Load Balancing instance with a custom domain name — including subdomain names and the zone apex*.

Comment: How can I create an API with Beanstalk if I can't direct requests through the load balancer? How do I properly communicate with my Beanstalk app?

Comment: @GeoffNoble: I'm not sure I can follow, why should a call to example.com/resource provided by an API hosted on Elastic Beanstalk not work as expected? I've expanded my answer regarding _Using Domain Names With Elastic Load Balancing_ to hopefully clarify the underlying concept - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> But I have an Elastic Beanstalk app. It can create and remove
>   instances as needed. It has a load balancer. How can I get these
>   features (Elastic IP and Elastic Beanstalk) to work together?

Starting with [September 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-network-load-balancer-effortless-scaling-to-millions-of-requests-per-second/) you can use [Network load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) within beanstalk. It supports static IP addresses for the load balancer. You can also assign one Elastic IP address per subnet enabled for the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

If you access your app through mydomain.com/someApiCall, the Elastic IP is not even in the picture. The ElasticBeanstalk gives you an url that looks like this:

http://myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com

you can just have your domain forward to myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com