# Trying to have a static IP with Elastic Beanstalk applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, reverse-proxy, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elastic-ip

My goal is to deploy a web application to Elastic Beanstalk and allow for a user to access that application from their corporate network.  Their network controls access to sites using IP addresses and IP address ranges.

I'm not aware of any way to define a static IP to an EB environment.  **Is it possible?**

An alternative approach I was considering is setting up a reverse proxy running on an EC2 instance.  That instance would be assigned an elastic IP and requests would be forwarded to the EB environments.  **Does that seem like a feasible approach?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I attach an Elastic IP to an Elastic Beanstalk app?](https://serverfault.com/questions/360613/how-do-i-attach-an-elastic-ip-to-an-elastic-beanstalk-app)